# Why is my data converted to ASCII using Serial.print function in arduino?

Tags: string, arduino

I am coding a small software to send data with an RN2483 transciever, and I have realised that my data is converted to ASCII when I sent it through serial. It is to say, I have the following part in the sender, the data has to be HEX

```
String aux = String(message.charAt(i),HEX);
dataToBeTx = "radio tx " + aux+ "\r\n";
Serial1.print(dataToBeTx)
```

On the receiver I am reading Serial1 till I get the message, which I receive properly, however it is an ASCII representation of the HEX data, and I would like to have it HEX, I mean, I send HI that is converted to HEX (H I=>0x48 0x49) on the receiver if I translate that value to HEX again I got different things than my H or I , so I guess it is being encoded in ASCII, how can I ride off from that?

Thanks in advance,

regards

Comment: This is a bit unclear. What do you mean by having it HEX and being ASCII? You can only send it two ways: direct bytes (meaning H and I in ASCII) or ASCII representation of the bytes (meaning the text 0x48 0x49). If the first, just send the `message`.

Comment: What I mean, is that I have to send HEX values, not ascii ones, but I do see that my HEX data is being mapped to ASCII

Comment: Again, can you show what you actually mean. What is "send HEX values"? Does it work when you just have `dataToBeTx = "radio tx " + message + "\r\n";` and send that? Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unclear what you are trying to achieve. The first line in your code converts a single character into a **string** in hexadecimal. For example:

```C++
void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();

  String aux = String('A', HEX);
  Serial.print ("aux = ");
  Serial.println (aux);

}  // end of setup

void loop ()
{
}  // end of loop
```

Output:

```
aux = 41
```

So the 'A' in my code (internally represented as 0x41) has now become two ASCII characters: `4` and `1`. That is, a string which is two bytes long.

So, in a sense, you can say it is already in hex.

> if I translate that value to HEX again I got different things than my H or I

Well, yes, if you translate it "again" then you would get 0x34 and 0x31.

Do you want to send `A` in this case, `41` or something else?

Comment: I would like to send just a 0x41, I could find out that it was the function Serial1.print the one which was encoding it as ASCII characters, so what I did was a ASCII to HEX function on the receiver side